# Group rows by 6 month periods going back from today in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I'm trying to get a count of rows with TimeStamps going back in 6 month groups from today. For instance, I'd want to print Year, then which half of the year, then the count of records containing in that group.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month, 6, TimeStamp),0), DATEPART(Year, TimeStamp), count(*)
FROM Table
WHERE row1 = 'Blah'
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 6, TimeStamp),0), DATEPART(Year, TimeStamp)
ORDER BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 6, TimeStamp),0), DATEPART(Year, TimeStamp)
```

But it doesn't give me the expected groups.

Comment: Please provide some details. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take advantage of *SQL Server* integer division to compute the semester number.

```
SELECT YEAR(TimeStamp) year, 1 + MONTH(TimeStamp) / 7 semester, count(*)
FROM mytable 
WHERE row1 = 'Blah'
GROUP BY YEAR(TimeStamp), 1 + MONTH(TimeStamp) / 7
ORDER BY year, semester
```

Eg :

- From January (month `1`) to June (`6`), the integer division by 7 returns `0` : `+ 1` makes it the first semester
- starting from July, the division returns `1`

Comment: what  `12 semester` do? I mean I can guess for context but first time I see it

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : yes that was buggy... query updated now

Comment: I think I see it now. Is `semester` an alias? because you copy/pasted to the group by.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : yes that was a copy/paste error, fixed just now. Thanks again !

Comment: Thanks x3 now @JuanCarlosOropeza. I have to be more careful when tumbling answers or edits...

Comment: No problem, at first tought was some kind of date function I didnt knew to convert to semester like `datepart`

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use `DataAdd()` function. Try the following query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, TimeStamp), 
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,[Date]) >= 3 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END as [Semester], count(*)
FROM Table
WHERE row1 = 'Blah'     
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, TimeStamp), 
         CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,[Date]) >= 3 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
ORDER BY DATEPART(Year, TimeStamp),[Semester]
```

If you are looking to calculate quarter then use:

```
DATEPART(quarter,[Date]) as [Quarter]
```